# League of legends to hide HUD and show mini-map only?

Tags: league-of-legends

I want to hide all HUD boards and display only the `mini map`.

Searching around in the in-game Hotkeys menu though found nothing related.

So how can we do that?

Answer (score 3):

As far as I know you cannot hide the HUD while still showing the minimap.

You can hide the HUD (including the minimap) in the *Hotkeys* menu. Expand the *Display* section and set a hotkey for *Show/Hide HUD*. Then while in game you can simply push whatever you set and the HUD will disappear.[image: show hide hud options]

Since it hides the minimap you will probably want to have it active most of the time but perhaps hide it when a teamfight is happening/about to happen.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying my question - that's exactly why I asked here.